# Sending multiple emails with Python consecutively but some are missing

Tags: python, email, smtp

I was trying to send around 10+ emails (each has an Excel file attached) consecutively by invoking the below Python function send_email(), which is based on the sample code shared by the tutorials on the web.

Somehow I found that though the 10+ emails are sent without errors/exceptions, occasionally some of the emails are not recipeved by the recipients. I checked the Sent box of the specified sender email account, for the emails that weren't received by the recipients, they are not in the sender's Sent box either.

I speculated that it could be due to those consecutive invocations of send_email() overflooded the SMTP server (but not sure) so I added 1 sec delay between the invocation (as specified below). However, the issue still happens occasionally. Now I'm trying to increase the delay from 1sec to 10sec.

Please kindly advise if my speculation is in the right direction and if there is anything I need to do to better pinpoint the root cause. Thanks a lot.

My code is as follows:

(a) Invoking send_email() consecutively in a loop. For each loop assign the corresponding email recipients, subject, message, and Excel attachment as the inputs.

(b) To add delays in between send_email() calls, time.sleep(1) is invoked to add 1 sec delay in the hope of not to overflow the SMTP server.

(c) The code of send_email() is as follows:

```
#Email the generated Excel file out
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os.path
def send_email(email_recipients, email_subject, email_message, attachment_location = ''):

    email_sender = 'xxx' #xxx is the sender's email address 
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_sender
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(email_recipients)
    msg['Subject'] = email_subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(email_message, 'plain'))

    if attachment_location != '':
        filename = os.path.basename(attachment_location)
        attachment = open(attachment_location, "rb")
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(attachment.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
        msg.attach(part)

    try:
        mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
        mailserver.ehlo()
        mailserver.starttls()
        mailserver.login('xx', 'xxxx') # xx and xxxx are the credentials for the smtp server
        text = msg.as_string()
        mailserver.sendmail(email_sender, email_recipients, text)
        print('email sent')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("SMPT server connection error")
    finally:
        mailserver.quit()

return True
```

Comment: According to the [smtplib documentation on `sendmail`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail), `If this method does not raise an exception, it returns a dictionary, with one entry for each recipient that was refused`. You're not doing _anything_ with the returned value, so you could be getting refusals but you're just throwing out the dictionary with them in it. So, definitely make that change and then test to see what's in your return value when an email doesn't get sent. Then you can handle the case and possibly retry, depending on the failure reason.

Comment: SMTP email severs notify (via email) about delivery problems/delays **after hours** (usually 4h).  Have you waited "half day" for such notifications?